# Is there any other way to use react-multi-carousel with NEXT.js and React/Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-multi-carousel

I imported [react-multi-carousel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-multi-carousel) module and set the simple carousel.
But it's not working. There are no `<li>` tags.

Rendered HTML is below.

`<ul class="react-multi-carousel-track " style="transition:none;overflow:unset;transform:translate3d(0px,0,0)"></ul>`

```
<div className={classes.profileCarousel}>
    <Carousel
        additionalTransfrom={0}
        arrows={false}
        autoPlaySpeed={0}
        centerMode={false}
        className={classes.carousel}
        customButtonGroup={<ButtonGroup/>}
        customDot = {<CustomDots/>}
        dotListClass={classes.customDotList}
        draggable
        focusOnSelect={false}
        infinite={true}
        keyBoardControl
        minimumTouchDrag={80}
        partialVisible
        renderButtonGroupOutside
        renderDotsOutside
        responsive={responsive}
        showDots
        sliderClass=""
        slidesToSlide={1}
        swipeable
    >
        {profiles.map(element => {
            return <ProfileCard props={element} key="as"/>
        })}
    </Carousel>
</div>
```

stack: `next.js` `typescript` `material-ui`

What's wrong with it?

Comment: Please add **react-multi-carousel** link in you question. It will be easier for those who will look at the package.

Comment: What code are you using to use the module?

Comment: @DanHarper NEXT.js with typescript.

Comment: Could you please copy/paste your code into your question?

Comment: One obvious problem ist the key of `ProfileCard`.This has to be a unique key.

Comment: Are you certain your `profiles` array contains elements?

Comment: @juliomalves yes. I have checked without a carousel. it works.

Comment: Solved. Change the carousel parent style `display:flex` to `display:block`. Not sure why this is not work with `display: flex`. Anybody knows?

Comment: Now latest version react-multi-carousel 2.8.4 need display: grid. And now its not work with display: block or display: flex.

Answer (score 0):

I already had this problem with this lib.

Basically it is because the brake points have not been set correctly.

This is a standard object I created, try using it and see if it works for you.

```
export const carouselBreakPoints = {
  desktopWide: {
    breakpoint: {
      max: 2560,
      min: 1421,
    },
    items: 6,
    partialVisibilityGutter: 40,
  },
  laptopM: {
    breakpoint: {
      max: 1420,
      min: 0,
    },
    items: 5,
    partialVisibilityGutter: 40,
  },
  laptopL: {
    breakpoint: {
      max: 1150,
      min: 0,
    },
    items: 4,
    partialVisibilityGutter: 30,
  },
  laptop: {
    breakpoint: {
      max: 940,
      min: 0,
    },
    items: 3,
    partialVisibilityGutter: 30,
  },
  tabletL: {
    breakpoint: {
      max: 750,
      min: 0,
    },
    items: 1.7,
    partialVisibilityGutter: 30,
  },
  mobile: {
    breakpoint: {
      max: 400,
      min: 0,
    },
    items: 1,
    partialVisibilityGutter: 30,
  },
};
```

Comment: You didn't check my code carefully. I have added a responsive prop but it doesn't show. And now I know how to fix it but not sure the reason. Please add that reason if you know.